# Recommend a library(an API) to recognize the shapes in the picture

Tags: image-processing, image-recognition, pattern-recognition

I need a library(with an API) which can take as input an image and recognize shapes from it, returning the coordinates of the shapes.

The deployment of the library must be simple, something in the form of a DLL but not a full blown app(for example Mathematica).

It doesn't have to be perfect, an approximation of the shape is fine but it shouldn't output overlapped shapes.

Here is an example of an input image

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what you mean? In this image, what are the shapes that you would expect as output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenCV: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/

This isn't an API, but it is an open source, cross platform, multi language library for this kind of thing.

OpenCV features quite a few image processing and computer vision tools that can help with object  detection, among other things.